# CS0101: The namespace already contains a definition for className

Tags: asp.net, wcf

> I am getting a strange error while trying to run a WCF service on
>   browser, Project is building fine on visual studio without any error
>   but gives crash with below details on browser. It is hosted in IIS. The class in declared only one in project and not duplicated, same project works fine on old machine but getting error on new machine where I tried to configure it. I think the one of reason it might be its creating temporary files of all the files in project inside Temporary ASP.NET Files folder, I tried to delete them but they get created every time when I build the project.

c:\windows\system32\inetsrv> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe" /t:library /utf8output /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activation\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activation.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\ingredientmatcher\b23748f5\43a1de34\App_GlobalResources.6a17zz1v.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\ingredientmatcher\b23748f5\43a1de34\assembly\dl3\9b041b3d\a0018c9c_d2d4d401\IngredientMatcher.MailSender.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\ingredientmatcher\b23748f5\43a1de34\assembly\dl3\83da1256\d2898c9c_d2d4d401\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\ingredientmatcher\b23748f5\43a1de34\assembly\dl3\e5745b7b\00098296_f41cd501\AWSSDK.Core.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.DynamicData\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.DynamicData.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\ingredientmatcher\b23748f5\43a1de34\assembly\dl3\81ab8890\7ada0cf9_141ed501\IngredientMatcher.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Activities.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\ingredientmatcher\b23748f5\43a1de34\assembly\dl3\6d63ab44\00f6e840_ec86d401\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\ingredientmatcher\b23748f5\43a1de34\assembly\dl3\d4905370\0012374f_ec86d401\System.Web.Http.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\ingredientmatcher\b23748f5\43a1de34\assembly\dl3\111dfb93\41ea8c9c_d2d4d401\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\ingredientmatcher\b23748f5\43a1de34\assembly\dl3\783cecad\0043550b_f51cd501\AWSSDK.SimpleNotificationService.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader\v4.0_1.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\ingredientmatcher\b23748f5\43a1de34\assembly\dl3\23e8d013\00b8417c_79f8d401\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\ingredientmatcher\b23748f5\43a1de34\assembly\dl3\c1ca991e\00445b94_ec86d401\System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activities.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /out:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\ingredientmatcher\b23748f5\43a1de34\App_Code.uw2nyizu.dll" /D:DEBUG /debug+ /optimize- /w:4 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701;612;618 /warnaserror-  "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\ingredientmatcher\b23748f5\43a1de34\App_Code.uw2nyizu.63.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\ingredientmatcher\b23748f5\43a1de34\App_Code.uw2nyizu.33.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\ingredientmatcher\b23748f5\43a1de34\App_Code.uw2nyizu.57.cs"

Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.7.3190.0

for C# 5
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

> This compiler is provided as part of the Microsoft (R) .NET Framework,
>   but only supports language versions up to C# 5, which is no longer the
>   latest version. For compilers that support newer versions of the C#
>   programming language, see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=533240
>
> d:\IM\IM-API\App_Code\BEU\FetchEbookRecipeDetailsBE.cs(58,18): error
>   CS0101: The namespace 'IngredientMatcher.App_Code.BEU' already
>   contains a definition for 'RetrieveCountryFlagUrlBE'
>   d:\IM\IM-API\App_Code\BEU\Recipe.cs(100,18): (Location of symbol
>   related to previous error)

Comment: Hard to confirm without the code but a "guess" from the message would be that FetchEbookRecipeDetailsBE.cs line 58 and Recipe.cs line 100 both define a type called `RetrieveCountryFlagUrlBE`...?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: RetrieveCountryFlagUrlBE.cs exists in same file which has Recpe.cs. RetrieveCountryFlagUrlBE.cs is not duplicated, if I comment it then I keep getting same error in other files in project.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: Do you have some solution for this?

Comment: I had this issue, here was my solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63528790/tfs-visual-studio-cs0101-the-namespace-already-contains-a-definition-for-cl/63528791#63528791